# Flutter: How to get the GitHub master version of a firebase plugin

Tags: git, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

Hi I'm currently trying to get the master version of the firebase_storage plugin. However I get the following error

> fatal: unable to look up FirebaseExtended (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
> exit code: 128

This is my pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_storage:
   git:
      url: git://FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_storage/firebase_storage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to get the master version of a firebase plugin use the code below

```
  firebase_storage:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire
      path: packages/{packageName}/{packageName}
```

Where {packageName} represents the firebase plugin

e.g.

firebase_storage

firebase_analytics

cloud_firestore